# How to build a keyboard

Tags: keyboard, computer-building

I have not found an ideal keyboard. Therefore I would like to attempt to build my own.

I have a rough idea of how I would like it to work. It wouldn't be anything like a conventional keyboard. It would be more like the datahand than anything else. I figure I should start by purchasing keys/switches and try soldering them to the USB interface of a torn apart USB keyboard.

Am I on the right track? If so where can I purchase keys/switches? Anyone know any good tutorials that may help?

Comment: What is your idea of an *ideal* keyboard?  If you don't fancy the plethora of non-mechanical key-switch keyboards, perhaps you could give the mechanical key-switch keyboards a go.

Comment: I really like the .com button that iphone has. Saved me quite a lot of time. Maybe a http://www. button can work too

Comment: My ideal keyboard would be one that allows me to use it with my hands and arms resting in any position I find most comfortable at the time; resting on my laptop, hanging down by my side. My left hand over here and my right hand over there. Standing up, reclining. The keyboard should be a more natural extension to my hands, not some rectangular device in front of me I must conform to giving me rsi. My vision is a glove like device which can be worn. Doesn't have to be pretty or something to improve typing speed. Just something which will be more comfortable for my long days at a keyboard.

Comment: http://hackedgadgets.com/2006/05/19/top-5-diy-glove-keyboards/

Comment: http://svenbuschbeck.net/wordpress/portfolio/keyboard-gloves/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Digikey](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?lang=en&site=US&WT.z_homepage_link=hp_go_button&KeyWords=keyswitch&x=0&y=0) - have fun - it's a very ambitious project.

One thing occurred to me regarding re-using the circuitry from an existing keyboard. It may be tuned to the particular characteristics of the switches used in the original for things like debounce, etc. I don't know how much of a difference that will make, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you Dennis. That does get me going. I suppose there could be many complications along the way. My hope is that the complexity is in a similar level as this usb keyboard hack: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3NxQ60E72k

Answer (score 0):

Could you prototype it by using some of the keys on a conventional keyboard and trying out the drivers you'll need to write. That way all the electronics to scan the keypresses is in place & if you like it you can take it to the next level.